# Prove $\int_{\Delta(0,1)} \frac{d\lambda(\zeta)}{|\zeta-z||\zeta-w|} \leq C \log \frac{C}{|z-w|}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have trouble when reading a proof of H"older continuity of the solution $u$ of the $\bar{\partial}$-equation $\bar{\partial}u=f$. My problem is the following estimate

$\int_{\Delta(0,1)} \frac{d\lambda(\zeta)}{|\zeta-z||\zeta-w|} \leq C \log \frac{C}{|z-w|}, \forall z,w\in \Delta(0,1), z\neq w$,

where $\Delta(0,1)\subset \mathbb{C}$ is the unit disk, $C\gg1$ is a constant and $\lambda(\zeta)$ is the Lebesgue measure.

I don't know how to estimate the blow up speed of the integral above. Can anyone help me to estimate it?